# Blueetooth auto-start not working

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, bluetooth, 18.10

I'm using ubuntu 18.10. In the past I probably made a change for my bluetooth to not start on startup but I do not remember the change. Now, I want to restore it back to normal but I couldn't find a way. Every time I start-up my system the bluetooth icon is not even appearing. When I start it from the applications it says daemon not running etc. I checked "blueetoth/main.conf" but "AutoEnable=true" exists. If I do

```
 sudo service bluetooth start
```

it works but when I restart my computer, the problem is back again.

Edit:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

This didn't solve the problem, too.

Comment: I might not be able to fix your problem but i can offer you an workaround: 
`( crontab -l ; echo "@reboot sudo service bluetooth start") | crontab -` Run this in your terminal to set a cronjob that restarts your bluetooth service on reboot.

Answer (score 4):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.
the problem was that I could not turn on bluetooth

it was solved by the command:

```bsh
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

I had to do this every time I booted into ubuntu.
to make it permanent when booting into ubuntu I used the command mentioned above:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the following command in order to enable bluetooth service from systemd boot system.

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```